# sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed (Python)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, unique-constraint

I am using Python and Sqlite 3 for a program

I have created following two tables in my database

```
theCursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    taxpayers(txp_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, type TEXT)""")

theCursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    inventory(txp_id TEXT, item TEXT, hscode TEXT, rate TEXT, qty TEXT, stock TEXT, UNIQUE(txp_id, hscode)
""")
```

I want to add a unique combination for txp_id and hscode in inventory table.
When I run my program and try to add record into inventory, I get this error:

```
program v6.py", line 217, in addToItemDB
    theCursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory VALUES(:txp_id, :item, :hscode, :rate, :qty, :stock)",
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: inventory.txp_id
```

Please help

The txp_id is unique for first table

In second table I want to have many hscodes for every txp_id so kept the combination unique so that evey row will be unique even if each of them is not unique in this table.

I add the first record successfully but when I add another record I get this error even if I enter different hscode for same txp_id

Comment: The table already contains a row with that txp_id and hscode (probably from an earlier execution of the program.)

Comment: I already checked by printing everything in terminal from inventory table. There is no such row already in the table.

Comment: Actually, looking closer at the error message, it refers ONLY to txp_id, not to the combination of txp_id and hscode.  So I'm guessing the inventory table was created with `txp_id` as a primary key, and you're trying to add another row with the same txp_id.  (The code here does not set a primary key on that table, but it uses `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, which will not replace an existing table definition, so I'm guessing that table was created earlier by different code which did set txp_id as a primary key).

Comment: I removed the old database and new one generated is working.